# How do I cast an Array<AnyObject> to an empty array variable?

Tags: casting, swift

**Problem:** I can't assign a string array (typed as 'AnyObject') to an empty array.

Steps:
1. Get a dictionary containing strings & arrays. 
2. Grab an array from this dictionary via the key 'photos'. 
   Note: Xcode's warning suggest that I give the explicit type 'AnyObject'. 
3. Create an empty array. 
4. Attempt to assign it (failed).

```
let responseDictionary = responseDict as [String : AnyObject]
let ricPhotos:AnyObject = responseDictionary["photos"]!              
var thePhotos:Array<AnyObject>?              
thePhotos = ricPhotos  <--- fails
```

Compiler Error:

```
...'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'Array<AnyObject>'
```

**Question:** How do I assign 'ricPhotos' to the empty array 'thePhotos' and preferably cast 'AnyObject' to 'String'?

---

**Revision**

```
let responseDictionary = responseDict as [String : AnyObject]
var anyObject: AnyObject? = responseDictionary["photos"]
```

Okay, 'anyObject' appears to be a Dictionary, and inside it is 'photo' which is an array; as seen in the data.
Here's some of the data(anyObject):

```
{
    page = 1;
    pages = 1334;
    perpage = 100;
    photo =     (
                {
            farm = 3;
            "height_m" = 336;
            "height_s" = 161;
            "height_sq" = 75;
            "height_t" = 67;
            id = 15166756998;
            isfamily = 0;
            isfriend = 0;
            ispublic = 1;
            owner = "127012961@N08";
            secret = 053032f300;
            server = 2941;
            title = "You @NYPL";
            "url_m" = "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2941/15166756998_053032f300.jpg";
            "url_s" = "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2941/15166756998_053032f300_m.jpg";
            "url_sq" = "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2941/15166756998_053032f300_s.jpg";
            "url_t" = "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2941/15166756998_053032f300_t.jpg";
            "width_m" = 500;
            "width_s" = 240;
            "width_sq" = 75;
            "width_t" = 100;
        },
        ...etc.
```

I want to grab the 'photo' array.  But I can't downcast 'anyObject' to 'Dictionary' so that I can subscript it. I tried:

```
var anyObject:Dictionary = responseDictionary["photos"]
```

But I got:

> '(String, AnyObject)' is not convertible to '[String : AnyObject]'

So I'm stuck with:

```
var anyObject: AnyObject? = responseDictionary["photos"]
```

So with anyObject, I tried to access 'photos':

```
let RicPhotos = anyObject["Photo"] as [String : AnyObject]
```

...I also tried:

```
let RicPhotos = anyObject["Photo"] as Array<Dictionary<String,String>>
```

But I got:

> 'AnyObject?' does not have a member named 'subscript'

I can see the data, but I can't extract into an empty variable.

I attempted to downcast to a specific type (Dictionary) but the compiler refuses.

There *must* be a strait forward way of getting an embedded array from a dictionary whilst casting to its respective cast (without the 'anyObject').

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited my answer to fit your edit...

```
let responseDictionary = [:] as [String : AnyObject]
var photosDic: AnyObject? = responseDictionary["photos"]
if let photosDic = photosDic as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
    var photosArray: AnyObject? = photosDic["photo"]
    if let photosArray = photosArray as? Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> {
        //There you go
    }
}
```

Comment: let ricPhotos:Array = responseDic["photos"] <-- I get the compiler error: '(String, AnyObject)' is not convertible to 'Array<T>'

Comment: "let photos = anyObject as? Array<String>" <- returns nil.  Swift is frustrating.

Comment: Does it fix your issue ?